# How to use output of TruncatedSVD() as input to neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, svd, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset(contains sentences) on which I need to perform vectorization and then  dimensionality reduction through TruncatedSVD() to reduce no. of features to 100.

Then i want to use that svd output as input to neural network. But i cannot keep track of the output label after doing svd, what should i do?

[I used pipeline to achieve this to perform logistic regression.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFuUo.png)
But i need to perform neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`MLPClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html):

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = # Your dataset

svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100, algorithm='arpack')
net = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),
                    learning_rate_init=0.01,
                    learning_rate='invscaling',
                    max_iter=500,
                    solver='adam')
pipe = Pipeline([('svd', svd), ('net', net)])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
test_score = pipe.score(X_test, y_test)  # Accuracy on test set
```

Comment: I tried this but got error while getting score from pipeline. 
ValueError: X has 543 features, but TruncatedSVD is expecting 2816 features as input.

Comment: @BISHALAdhikari What is the feature dimension of your training data? 2816? If yes, then your validation/test data should also have 2816 features, not 543. Your error is not related to the code above.